# Changes in android manifest of live app make update fail?

Tags: android

I am an experienced android developer, I haven't found anything in my search.

I got this from client "you can’t update it,your apk is not going to update live app" in context to changes done in the manifest file

Making what sort of changes in the android manifest file would make android application update fail?

assuming
1. Version updated
2. Same package name
3. Same Keystore

P.S I have gone through this post as well 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html